# Proving injective continuous function is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and *X* is a compact metric space, show that every continuous injective function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism of *X*. 
  $(f\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n)$

So I persumed that I have to show that f is an open map from $X\to\mathbb{R}^n$:
Let *U* be an open set in *X*. Then $U^c$ is closed in *X*, which is compact, so $U^c$ is also compact. Since $f$ is continuous $f(U^c)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then I got stuck. Does this lead to $f(U^c)$ being closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$? is it sufficient enough?

Comment: You mean a homeomorphism *onto its image* right? so between $X$ and $f(X) \subset \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is compact and $f$ continuous, then $f(U)$ is also compact. In addition, if $f$ is injective (that is, bijective from $U$ to $f(U)$), then $f$ has a continuous inverse. I think you can easily find proofs about the relevant theorems in any intro topology tutorial or, e.g., chapter 2 of Baby Rudin.